# Why do the electron and positron creation operators anti-commute?

Tags: fermions, antimatter, identical-particles, grassmann-numbers, positronium

I am learning QFT and is baffled by a minor problem.

The electron and the positron should be distinguishable, as they have different charges. So why do their creation operators anti-commute? They should commute with each other, just like the creation operators of the electron and the proton commute with each other.

Comment: Related: [System of distinguishable fermions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/656848)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I remember, you can choose creation operators of **different** fermions to commute or to anti-commute, both choices should provide correct results if used consistently.

Comment: Your memory is correct. The keywords are [Klein transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/552550).